# Any working example of a contextual outlook add-in in OWA

Tags: office-js

We are trying to make our Outlook Add-in contextual, meaning, activating upon a regex match.I have tried everything according to the documentation but it just doesn't seem to work.

Looking at other plugins, I was not able to find any working examples.

Is this still supported? Was the feature lost in an update? I can't even get Microsofts own built-in Bing add-in to activate.

Does anyone have a working example of a contextual Outlook Add-in?

Comment: Hi Rick, we apologize for the frustration. Would you mind sharing with us the manifest file you're working with?

Comment: Hi Team, thanks for the reply. Maybe it is easier if you could share a working example we could look at? Because it is correct that also the BING add-in doesn't work contextually? Any working example would help us greatly!

Comment: Team. Could you please respond?

Comment: There is known issue for Bing Maps for a small number of users in Outlook.com. This is not likely the reason you are having trouble with contextual activation. Please provide your manifest so we can better understand the scenario that you are working on. We are working on a sample on the developer portal and will have it posted soon. There are also other scenarios where Outlook does not activate add-ins, for example, items protected by Information Rights Management (IRM).

Comment: ok, Thanks. Where should I send it to? Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Please add the relevant section to the question on stack overflow

Comment: I use this:

<Permissions>ReadItem</Permissions>
<Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
<Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Read"/>
<Rule xsi:type="ItemHasRegularExpressionMatch" 
    PropertyName="BodyAsPlaintext" 
    RegExName="Test" 
    RegExValue="Online"/>
</Rule>
<DisableEntityHighlighting>false</DisableEntityHighlighting>


Based on:
- https://github.com/OfficeDev/Outlook-Add-in-ScanForMe

But icon of add-in is always visible in read mode, and the word 'Online' is never highlighted in the body of any mails...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

[Contextual Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/contextual-outlook-add-ins) has some information that will help with using Detected Entities.

The legacy section of the manifest is being deprecated in Office 365. This includes the regular expression rules example you provided in the comments of your question. These rules can be used to highlight and activate on text but must be used in the [DetectedEntity](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/reference/manifest/extensionpoint.md#detectedentity) section in order to highlight contextually in Outlook on the Web for Outlook.com and Office 365.

The reason your manifest isn't working is because you may also have a [VersionOverrides](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/reference/manifest/versionoverrides.md) section (which is in the example you mentioned in the comments). The version overrides section overrides previous versions and is used to leverage [Add-In Commands](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/exchangedev/2017/01/20/add-in-commands-in-owa-and-outlook-on-the-mac/) and newer features in Outlook.

Please note that the DetectedEntity section must be included in Version Overrides 1.1 which is nested inside VersionOverrides 1.0. Since the sample doesn't include a DetectedEntity section in the version overrides section, the highlight rules you're providing are being overriden.